# CQRS or App Service?

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs

So I like the concepts of CQRS in our application, mainly because we already support event sourcing (conceptually, not following any prescriptions that you see out there).  However, it really seems like CQRS is geared toward Big Data, Eventual consistency, that kind of thing.  We are always going to be a Relational DB app, so I am not sure if it fits.

I also have concerns because I think I need to do some special things in my app layer.  When doing a read, I need to enforce security and filter data, things that are traditionally implemented in the application layer.

My first question is, does my app fit (a traditional MVC / Relational DB app)?  Or does it make more sense to have a traditional app layer and use a DTO Mapper?

My second question is, does it make sense to issue commands to your domain model out of a traditional application layer?  I like the idea of commands / command handlers and eventing.

Let me clarify my question.  I have concerns around data filtering that are tied to authorization.  When a user requests data, there has to be a filter that restricts access to certain data elements by removing them all together (So they are not returned to the caller), hiding the values, or applying masks to the data.  In a contrived example, for a Social Security Number, the user making the request may only be able to see the last 4 numbers, so the result would appear like ###-##-1234.

My assertion is that this responsibility goes in the Application layer.  I consider this an aspect, where all responses to queries or commands have to go through this filter mechanism.  Here is where my CQRS naivity shines through, perhaps it is that commands never return data, just pointers to data that are looked up through the read model?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First and foremost: **CQRS** and **Relational Databases** don't exclude each other. In advanced scenarios it may make sense to replace the SQL-based DB with other means of storage, but CQRS as a concept doesn't care about the persistence mechanism.

In the case of multiple views that depend on roles and/or users, the **Thin Read Layer** should probably provide multiple result sets:

1. One containing the full SSN for users that are authorized to access that information.
2. A different one for users that are not authorized to see that information
3. ...

These can be stored in a separate data store, but they can also be provided through SQL views if you work with a single SQL-based database.

In CQRS the **Application Service** still exists in the form of **Command Handlers**. These can be nested, i.e. handling authorization first, then posting the command to a contained command handler.

```
public class AuthorizationHandler {

    public CrmAuthorizationService(CrmCommandHandler handler) {
        _next = handler;
    }

    public void Handle(SomeCommand c) {
        if (authorized) _next.Handle(c);
    }
}

// Usage:
var handler = new CrmAuthorizationService(new CrmCommandHandler());
bus.Register<SomeCommand>(handler.Handle);
```

This way you can nest multiple handlers, e.g. as a *REST envelope*, for *logging*, *transactions*, etc.

**To answer your questions:**

**First:** Is CQRS a good fit for your app? No-one can tell without really digging into the specific requirements. Just because you use MVC and a relational DB doesn't mean anything when it comes to the pros and cons of CQRS.

**Second**: Yes, in some cases it can make sense to let your application layer interact with the client in a classical way and handle things like authentication, authorization, etc., and then issue commands internally. This can be useful when putting an MVC-based UI or a REST API on top of your application.

**Update in response to comment:**

In an ideal, puristic CQRS scenario Sally would have her own denormalized data for every view, e.g. a couple of documents in a NoSQL DB called *CustomerListForSally*, *CustomerDetailsForSally*, etc. These are populated with what she's allowed to see.

Once she gets promoted - which would be an important domain event - all her denormalized data would automatically be overwritten, and extended to contain what she's allowed to see now.

Of course we must stay reasonable and pragmatic, but this ideal should be the general direction that we're heading for.

In reality you probably have some kind of user/role or user/group based system. To be able to view sensitive information, you'd have to be member of a particular role or group. Each of these could have their defined set of views and commands. This doesn't need t be denoalized data It can be as simpe as a cope of SQL-Views:

- *CustomerDetailsForSupportStaff*
- *CustomerDetailsForSupportExecutive* with unmasked SSN
- *CustomerListForSupportStaff*
- *CustomerListForSupportExecutive* with customer revenue totals
- etc.

Comment: Thanks for the great response.  One question I have on the Read Layer, in the application the logic for determining data authorization is calculated at runtime.  For example, I could log in as Sally Smith today, and she can't see social security numbers.  Sally gets a promotion, and is therefore given access to more sensitive information.  The next time Sally logs in, she can see social security numbers.  Authorization determination is much more complex than this in reality.  In general, we retrieve the information first, then filter it since it is difficult to apply masking otherwise.

Comment: Ran out of room...where would this Authorization Logic lie?  In the thin read layer?  There has to be some collaborator that will take a result set in and a user, look up the appropriate filters, apply them to the result set, and return the result set, which ultimately gets passed through the Thin Read Layer, App Service, what have you.  Or is Filtering like this a presentation concern?

Comment: Thanks again for the clarity, I really appreciate your insight.  In the system, the masking of data is not fixed to a role, but is done through configuration and business rules (i.e. rules are loaded at runtime, and users are applied to the rules and data, and selectively certain data is masked).  So providing SQL Views does not work in my specific use case.  I have to essentially filter the data when it is requested somewhere in the code.  Sorry I didn't make this more clear from the outset.  So going back to my original post, where would this behavior fall in a CQRS implementation?

Comment: I like your insight and accept your answer.  Given than Security is something that isn't part of the core domain, but is an application concern, I am implementing security in the application layer.  I plan on using AspectJ to intercept requests and run different authorization checks.  The authorization check should be the same for most requests, so it should be a rather elegant solution.

Comment: @noplay Sounds very reasonable to me. Glad that I was able to help at least a bit.